# Xpath is not working on MouseOver(CatMenu) in Selenium

Tags: selenium, testing, xpath, intellij-idea, mouseover

There is problem about selenium for all web driver which cannot open mouseover menu.Altough assing to Xpath of element web driver cannot open Mouse Over (CatMenu) and log is that "Must provide a location for a move action".

i want to go n11.com web adress and over on Kitap, Müzik, Film, Oyun and click Kitap but its not working.
Thank you

```
@Test

public void  startWebDriver(){
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("http://www.n11.com");


Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='contentMain']/div/nav/ul/li[8]/a"))).perform();
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following code to achieve the same -

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://chromedriver.exe");
    driver =new ChromeDriver();     
    driver.get("http://www.n11.com/");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    WebElement menu =  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='catMenuItem']/a[@title='Kitap, Müzik, Film, Oyun']"));
    WebElement submenu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='subCatMenuItem']/a[@title='Kitap']"));

    Actions action = new Actions(driver);

    action.moveToElement(menu).moveToElement(submenu).click().build().perform();
```

Use some `Implicit Wait` to avoid timeout exceptions to find your web element
Use more specific `xpath` to find your web element.

In your case first you need to hover on `Kitap, Müzik, Film, Oyun` menu and then have to perform click on `Kitap` submenu

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `ExplicitWait` with more specific `XPath`:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("(//a[@title='Kitap, Müzik, Film, Oyun']")[2])));
// WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Kitap, Müzik, Film, Oyun")));
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.moveToElement(element).perform();
```

Comment: This code returns java.lang.NullPointerException and i couldnot find reason @Andersson

Comment: WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@title='Kitap, Müzik, Film, Oyun']"))); Thats return null point expection

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that there are two links with the same title and the first one is hidden... try to use `"(//a[@title='Kitap, Müzik, Film, Oyun']")[2]` instead...

Comment: or you can use `By.linkText("Kitap, Müzik, Film, Oyun")`

Comment: Xpathh shows different issue Error:(40, 134) java: array required, but org.openqa.selenium.By found @Andersson

Comment: Linktext shows same issue java.lang.NullPointerException
@Andersson